# Laravel store data to the pivot table eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, view, eloquent, laravel-blade

I am trying to store data to the DB from a form. I have table with columns `subject`, `subjectType(Economic, Informatic subject)` and `subjectType_subject(pivot table)`. I can store data to `Subject` table but I need to store id's to `subjectType_subject` table. In my view I have a dropdown nav - Economic subjects and Informatic subjects. If I would like to add Economic subject, I need to add ID's to pivot table to display it.

How can I do this please?

Now I can store data only to Subject table and it doesn't appear on Economic subjects section:

**SubjectController**

```
public function create() {
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'abbreviation' => 'required',
        'description' => ''
    ]);

    $subject = new Subject();
    $subject->name = $request->input('name');
    $subject->abbreviation = $request->input('abbreviation');
    $subject->description = $request->input('description');

    $subject->save();

    return redirect()->back()
         ->with('success', 'Úspěšne jsi vytvořil nový předmět.');
    }
}
```

**Subject Model**

```
public $table = 'Subject';

protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'abbreviation',
    'description'
];

public function subject_type() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subject_type',  'subjectType_subject');
}
```

**SubjectType Model**

```
public $table = 'SubjectType';

public function subject() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subject', 'subjectType_subject');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, try to fix your naming conventions. Things would be a lot easier if you follow laravel's naming convention. [Here is the guide](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions).

- **Table Name** should be snake_case (change `subjectType` to `subject_type`)
- **Pivot Tables** should be singular model names in alphabetical order (change `subjectType_subject` to `subject_subject_type`)
- **belongsToMany** should have a plural function name. (change `public function subject_type()` to `public function subject_types()` and also the `public function subject()` to `public function subjects()`

Then use laravels `attach` keyword in order to fill the pivot table.

```
$subject = new Subject();
$subject->name = $request->input('name');
$subject->abbreviation = $request->input('abbreviation');
$subject->description = $request->input('description');
$subject->save();

$subject->subject_types()->attach(id_of_your_subject_type); // for example, 
             the id of economics in your subject_type table is 1, then put 1 inside the parenthesis
```

Comment: thank you for advice.. I got error like this -> "Use of undefined constant subject_type_id - assumed 'subject_type_id

Comment: already solved it with adding '', but now i get error "Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::attach() must be of the type array, string given ... Can u help me with this please?

Comment: do you have data in your subject_type table?

Comment: yes, I have. I have query -> $subject->subject_types()->attach('subject_type_id', 'subject_id'); -- because both column is not null in pivot table

Comment: try `sync` instead of `attach` and tell me if there's any error

Answer (score 0):

Just add eloquent query below

```
 $subject->save();
```

Like:

```
$subjecttype= new SubjectType;
$subjecttype->subjectid= $request->input(‘subjectid’);
$subjecttype->save();

  return redirect()->back()
         ->with('success', 'Úspěšne jsi vytvořil nový předmět.')
```